# If I Run My app in any version except 2.2 then it gives error bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, bitmap

I have made my app for version 2.2. Now problem is like, its working properly for any resolution in version 2.2 but if I install it to anyother version(e.g. 2.1 or 2.3.3) and run it then it gives bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

Comment: Are you using different emulators to test this? Or are you using different devices?

Comment: for same emulator I just edit the version...like from 2.2 to 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues in the past. This post helped me a lot, check it out.

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)

Comment: But I can not sample image as it will reduce quality of it and change dimension of image...